# DPL3 RegEx: How to suppress display of matched parameters?

Tags: mediawiki, regex, mediawiki-extensions

I'm trying to match

```
{{Tag|Anteater}}
```

Regarding https://help.gamepedia.com/DPL:Parameters:_Criteria_for_Page_Selection#includematch, and https://help.gamepedia.com/DPL:Parameters:_Controlling_Output_Volume#include

The DPL statement

```
{{#dpl: 
    |uses=Template:Tag
    |includematch=/Anteater/
    |include={Tag}:1
}}
```

returns the expected page list:

> ScrapAnteater
>
> Scrap3Anteater

**Problem** is, it also displays the parameter "Anteater" after every page-name.

**How to show only the pagenames,** and suppress display of matched parameters, while still matching the parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be accomplished with the regex replace feature with comes bundled with DPL3.

**Simple solution:** use [dplreplace](https://help.gamepedia.com/DPL:Dplreplace) to remove the string.

```
{{#dplreplace:

{{#dpl: 
    |uses = Template:Tag
    |includematch = /Anteater/
    |include = {Tag}:1
}}

|Anteater}}
```

**Robust solution:** use [format](https://help.gamepedia.com/DPL:Parameters:_Controlling_Output_Format#format) statement to append an arbitrary delimiter before the string you want to remove, to ensure you don't remove the string from any page-titles which happen to contain the same string.

However, if the template is transcluded more than once on any page, then the `include` statement will repeat the parameter for each transclude on that page. Eg

> - ScrapAnteater
> - Scrap3AnteaterAnteaterAnteater

Therefor, you'll need to use a wildcard in the replace statement to remove *all* of them:

```
{{#dplreplace:

{{#dpl: 
    |uses = Template:Tag
    |format = ,\n* %PAGE%·,,
    |includematch = /Anteater/
    |include = {Tag}:1
}}

|·.*}}     <!-- .* wildcard here -->
```